# Flink scala project depends on flink java project so java map called instead of scala map

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I want to create a flink project written in scala.

when i importing

```
'flink-scala_2.11',
'flink-streaming-scala_2.11'
'flink-core',
```

i can run a code like:

```
val someEventScalaStream = myScalaStreamm.map{x=>x.Part3} (it is using scala map function)
```

but i see that for each:

```
flink-connector-rabbitmq_2.11
flink-connector-filesystem_2.11
flink-clients_2.11
```

all of them depends on 'flink-java'

so when all of them imported into my solution the project is trying to use the map function of the java version & doesn't compile.

any solution?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally apis for java and scala are put into separate packages. So make sure you use the right one. E.g. for `DataStream` you have

Java:

```
org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream
```

Scala:

```
org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.DataStream
```

In this case in scala it is recommended to import:

```
org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._
```

If that does not cover your question could you post a concrete example when a java version of a `map` function is used?